# Is it wrong for a Muslim to say hallelujah?

Tags: halal-haram, terminology

I have searched about both the literal and religious meaning and context of the word "Hallelujah", and I learned it is a Hebrew word, meaning "praise to God".

Is it okay for a Muslim to say Hallelujah?

Comment: Alhamdolillah means almost the same and is used by [Arabic speaking Jews and Christians](http://horsehints.org/IsraelBaruchHashem.htm), in addition to Muslims.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regards to your inquiry that asked:

> Is it okay for a Muslim to say Hallelujah

So, in case even it supposedly can be halal (God knows best), but there could be a significant point to pay heed. This point is related to the promotion of Jews. Actually whenever you use such Jews phrases or even symbols of the Jews, consequently you would promote their language from an aspect (except positive meaning of the words or phrases which you are saying). Then it would be nicer to ignore using such phrases that non-Muslim use them. Then try to use Islamic phrases instead. Such as Alhamdollelah and other Islamic (Arabic) phrases.

May Allah guide us

Comment: Yes that would be appropriate to use Islamic and specificlly Arabic terms in such cases and to avoid using other terms. May Allah Guide Us All. Amen

Comment: yeah dear Ali Malik. Hence we'd better try to promote Islam in different manners even in Talking. God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a scholar (I could be wrong too). But according to my knowledge I think it's better NOT for Muslim's to use the phrase, "Hallelujah." The reason is simple, even though the meaning is considered a good/halal in Islamic context, when you simply say 'Hallelujah' it reflects a thoughts of a Jewish/Christianity view of praising God which is NOT good and our prophet always advised not to do anything what the Jews/Christians would do. In this case, I think it's better to avoid such phrases and say 'Alhamdulillah' which has 2 things together with a broad meaning (Nouman Ali Khan explains). One is the appreciation as "Praise is for Allah," and the second part is "Thanks to Allah." So you decide, which is better? Hallelujah or Alhamdulillah.. The latter is always beneficent.

Peace.

Comment: P.S. I suggest you watch Nouman Ali Khan explaining, 'Alhamdulillah'.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLB75MaHgCk

Comment: Yes i have watched it and now have more clear thinking about it. jazakAllah

Answer (score 0):

Hallel a Hebrew word and also used in Arabic, since childhood when told to hallel means to say la illah illallah (God is one)  repeatedly, it's quite sad when you find a Muslim who is talking about Islam in English and speaking English with Arabic words mixed in there, confuses so many people, God is the English name for the Almighty which English speakers use, Allahis the Arabic name for the Almighty use by the Arabic speaking to Christian and Muslim every language has a different name for the Almighty.

The main objective of the Scriptures is to acknowledge the one true living God of the heavens and earth and as I mentioned earlier what hallelujah (hallel) means in Arabic, saying God is one acknowledging that he is one constantly is a way of praising God you're mighty, as I mentioned every single language has got a nine weeks for example Mary in English, Miriam in Arabic also Marie, Maria, this goes out to all the people from all different religions who try and divide and can't see that every language has only a different name for the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

It means " praise to GOD" as it is not Hebrew or Arabic word. The apostles where anointed by Holy Spirit and they speak in different tongues.It is a word from heaven. Heavenly language..

Comment: Pointing some references would be good.

Answer (score -4):

its haram to say hallelujah cuz it is the name of THEIR GOD and they usually use that word in church.i got this info from an ustadz. that's mean as a muslim we can't use that word to praise god/Allah or hear a song with hallelujah in the lyric its haram

Comment: name of their God? Whose God?
I'm a Catholic, and no, it's not a name of God.
It means praise the Lord.